# git for two versions of software (free and paid)

Tags: git, version-control, architecture

Is it possible with git, or any VCS, to maintain two versions of essentially the same software (a "free" version and a paid version) within one repository?  I envision a master branch (maybe the "free" branch) and a paid branch in which I merge the "free" branch into.

I am not well versed in this area so my thinking and terminology may not be entirely accurate.  I haven't tried this as even if it works, it may not be the best approach.  Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have pay locks in every part of the software for the free and paid versions, you can simply confine the pay locks to one or two classes.  Actually, the code for the paid and free versions should be exactly the same (only the installation key given to the user should change), unless you really are writing two programs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey While I completely agree with this, I am working with software that doesn't distribute well in a binary form and user contributions would be limited. Feature sets and data services would be added to the paid version.

Comment: I am writing it in PHP, so the source is available which is why I am looking to have a separate branch with more code.

Comment: Seems like you could create a branch for each major feature to be added.

Comment: But how would I go about maintaining the two versions?  Work primarily in the free branch for bug fixes and merge them into the paid branch?  I would have to be very careful not to do bug fixes in the paid branch or it would be a nightmare to merge back into the free branch; would it not?

Comment: nope, instead of a merge, just do a cherry-pick in that case.

Comment: @Chronial I had no idea that command existed.

Comment: Btw – do you want to open-source the free version?

Comment: @Chronial I'd like to, but I am not sure how open because I don't really want it to take on a life as another project.

Answer (score 0):

Such business logic should be implemented in build strategy. Use git to keep two similar code base is a big NO NO.

Even in interpreted language like PHP you still need to build. Your code should not be available for use directly from source code. At least you need to compile CSS, Javascript etc for production mode. So build is a must.

Now comes your free and paid version. I don't know how you separate them. I suppose a better logic is through plugins or moduals. Paid version has more or better functions which could be done by including separate plugins or moduals.

So the logic is simple now:

1. You keep a public repo to serve your free version.
2. You keep a private repo for paid version, which include 1) Advanced plugin/moduals. 2) Build strategy to fetch free repo and compile paid version.